# hide/show not working properly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with three rows of main information that all have a 'More Info' button attached, sort of like [wefollow.com](http://wefollow.com) and their info button.

When the 'More Info' link is clicked a `<tr>` with a class of "mi" slides down above the main info.

The problem that I am getting is hiding the `<tr>` before the 'More Info' link is clicked. There is just a blank space where the `<tr>` is. The info in the `<tr>` is being hidden with jQuery (script below) and then displays when 'More Info' is clicked.

I tried hiding the "mi" with CSS but when the 'More Info' button is clicked, nothing happens.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

### Scripts

#### index

```
<table>
    <tbody>

        <tr id="info-1"> </tr>
        <tr class="mi">
            <td>
                <div id="1" class="more-information" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="">
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> <a id="1" class="more-info" href="#">More info</a> </td>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### listing.js

```
$(function(){
    $(".more-information").hide();

    $(".more-info").click(function () {

    var divname= this.id;

    $("#"+divname).load("getinfo.php").slideToggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");

    return false;
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using tables for this task!

Answer (score 1):

First problem is you're repeating IDs. They need to be unique. That's no doubt throwing off your code.

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr id="info-1"> </tr>
  <tr class="mi">
    <td><div id="more-1" class="more-information">More information</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a id="1" class="more-info" href="#">More info</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

combined with:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.more-info").click(function() {
    $("#more-" + this.id).load("getinfo.php").slideToggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
  });
});
```

Not sure why you need to hide siblings in the above though.

Also, I wouldn't hide the "more-information" divs in jquery. Just add CSS for that:

```
div.more-information { display: none; }
```

Comment: tried the above, but still get a blank space on the page where the "mi" class is. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried entering getinfo.php in your browser? What does it return? Are you perhaps missing some arguments to it, like something to identify which "more info" data to return?

Comment: getinfo.php does work and displays but I can't seem to hide the "mi" class first and then show it when 'more-info' is cliked.

Here is a link to a picture of the site, the yellow square is the "mi" class.

http://i645.photobucket.com/albums/uu171/damicoa1/Picture2.png

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the `more-information` div but you are not hiding its parent element, the `<tr>` with class `mi`.  Try putting the `id` attribute in the `<tr>` instead of the enclosed div, and hiding the whole row.  Also, you'll have to take cletus' advice about not repeating id's and unnecessary sibling hiding.

Comment: the row does go away when I set tr.mi { display: none; } but I don't know how to display it back when the 'more-info' button is cliked without opening all three rows. Any thoughts?